# Assigning String Literals to Char Pointers

Tags: c++

Why do I get `warning : ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*'` when I assign a `char *` to a string literal? Can't I assign string literals to `char *` like in the C programming language? Also, I don't get the warning when I assign string literals to `const char *` and the book I'm currently reading (C++ primer) talks about string literals and `const char *` interchangebly. Why is that?

Comment: Of course you can do it in C, however C++ is not C. It's a completely different language, and you can't do it in C++ because, well, you can't. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: The compiler warns you when you assign a string literal to a `char*`, but not when you assign a string literal to a `const char*`. That's because the first isn't legal in C++. The compiler writers really aren't doing you a favor by only giving a warning, although that's allowed by the standard.